# Sharepoint online search not returning results

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions

I have written a simple SPFX webpart where I am trying to show content from a SharePoint list using search REST api.

I am using a custom permission level for some of the users, where they don't have "View Application Pages" permission.

All users who are having above custom permission doesn't get any result but as soon as "View Application Pages" permission is granted, they start getting result (after sometime, may be because ACL gets crawled).

If this permission is required for search results then how can I make some users just visitors on the site so that they just have read permission on site and can not see any application page.

Site Template : Communication Site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "View Application Pages" permission is required for search results. There is no option to get search results without "View Application Pages" permission.

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, but then how to achieve this scenario where I have to restrict some of the users to access the application pages like site content page ?